# Reverse engineering and relationship with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, macos, hibernate

The problem that I can not solve is the following:

I created a MySQL database and a java project to interact with it.
I'm using Hibernate to manage the persistence. The database is formed from two tables that are in a many-to-many relationship through a third table.

When I perform the operation of revense, then a buttom-up approach, Hibernate does not handle relationships between tables, that generates independent classes without considering the foreign key.

I state that I am working under OS X and using Eclipse Kepler IDE. A `hbm` file that Hibernate generates is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 13-apr-2015 14.16.34 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Esame" table="Esame" catalog="esercitazione2">
        <composite-id name="id" class="EsameId">
            <key-property name="matricola" type="int">
                <column name="matricola" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idmateria" type="int">
                <column name="idmateria" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="voto" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="voto" />
        </property>
        <property name="data" type="date">
            <column name="data" length="10" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2-apr-2015 16.13.37 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="it.esercitazione.Esame" table="Esame" catalog="esercitazione2">
        <composite-id name="id" class="it.esercitazione.EsameId">
            <key-property name="matricola" type="int">
                <column name="matricola" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idmateria" type="int">
                <column name="idmateria" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>

        <!-- missing -->
        <many-to-one name="materia" class="it.esercitazione.Materia" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="idmateria" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="studente" class="it.esercitazione.Studente" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="matricola" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="voto" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="voto" />
        </property>
        <property name="data" type="date">
            <column name="data" length="10" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see, **Hibernate does not take into account the many-to-one relationship**. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you defined relationships in your mysql db?

Comment: unless relationship is defined in db. your hibernate generation process will not consider it. Make sure the table storage engine is InnoDB

Comment: I created the foreign key and the table storage engine is InnoDB. So this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The name of the tables should be written in lower case.